# Problems with PS3 on non-HDMI

Tags: ps3

My PlayStation 3 has been hooked up on HDMI pretty much since the day I got it.  Today, I brought it to a friend's house, who does not have a TV with HDMI.  However, the system is not displaying any image or sound over the RCA connection.

Presuming all hardware to be good, is there something I'm supposed to do to reset the system so that it can work with a non-HD TV?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The trick is to

1. Start with the ps3 in 'off' mode, when it is showing the 'red' light
2. Hold down the power button [ you will hear a first beep ], keep holding it for a few more seconds [ you will hear another beep ]
3. Now your display settings are reset. If you turn on the ps3 now, it will detect the new display source and configure it.

[Here](http://www.portfolioofpb.com/blog/update-ps3-blank-screen-switch-inputs-hdmi-to-composite-to-hdmi) is a very detailed description of this

You can also use this trick to reset the HDMI connection if you move the PS3 from a 1080p tv to one that cannot display 1080p.

Comment: @bronzebeard - I presume this *only* clears the display settings?

Comment: I am not sure. I will check and get back.

Comment: Wow.  Now I know how my display settings keep getting mysteriously reset.  Curse my children and their stubby fingers!

Comment: @bronzebeard - Tested and works as described.  Resets video settings only.  Thanks!

Comment: Great! I was just about to move my ps3 to my friends tv. Thank you